# I get "Host is not valid or is not accepted by Laminas\Uri\Uri" after upgrading Magento 2.3.6 to Magento 2.3.7

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.7

after upgrading Magento 2.3.6p1 to Magento 2.3.7 I get the following error opening the Frontend:

Host is not valid or is not accepted by Laminas\Uri\Uri

I already cleared caches etc. and rebuilt the indices. Still there is this error.

Can someone give me a hint what to do, to resolve that error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using any mageplaza's extension?

Comment: Yes, Better PopUp

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command once

**

> rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/*
> var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/*
> pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*

**

hope that helps you

Comment: Sorry, this had no effect on the problem.

Comment: I found out that the problem was the URL of my staging site. The original URL was like magento2.staging.mydomain.de. After changing to an URL like staging.mydomain.de everything worked fine.

Comment: Happy to here you found it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved same issue after upgrade 2.3.3 to 2.3.7. Issue due to laminas/laminas-escaper (2.7.1) in 2.3.7 version.

**You can add the following to your composer.json and run composer update.**

```
"require": {
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.7",
"laminas/laminas-escaper": "2.7.0"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For this error - host is not valid or is not accepted by laminas\uri\uri

comment out at C:\xampp\htdocs\the-webster\vendor\laminas\laminas-uri\src
at around line no 171
// $this->parse($uri);

Hope this will help someone in critical condition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).